# Azure Stream Analytics: Calculate COUNT(*) for periods more than 7 days

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I have a stream of user data being ingested by [Azure Event Hubs] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/).

I am aggregating that data using [Azure Stream Analytics] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/) by the COUNT(*) of views for a given productId.

I then update the productId's view count in CosmosDB.

In a prototype, I ran a query in a Stream Analytics job like this:

```
SELECT
    productId, COUNT(*) AS views
INTO
    cosmosDbOutput
FROM
    eventHubInput
TIMESTAMP BY moment
GROUP BY productId, System.Timestamp()
```

This query upserted the views of a product for *all time*.

I ran a query in Cosmos to retrieve the most popular views:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM c
ORDER BY c.views DESC
```

What I'd like to do is only maintain the views that a product has seen in the **last 30 days**.

I see that Stream Analytics jobs have [windowing functions] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-window-functions) that have a max time of 7 days.

Given that limit on windowing functions, is there a way to write a query that aggregates over 7+ days?

If not, is there a different approach in terms of tooling or storage I should consider?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your past data won`t change, so there's no need to use Stream Analytics for it. Once you calculate the count, you can persist it on a SQL Database or Table Services (Cosmos / Storage) and create a materialized view.

[image]

more info about materialized view: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/materialized-view

Comment: You're right that past data won't change - my concern is calculating the count and maintaining it as new data comes in.

Comment: You can control the interval using Getdate() - 30 for example. Use Stream Analytics for real time data, output it ti SQL to get data for a particular range of dates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-sql-output-perf